# How to transform a Leaflet L.latlng object to a boolean or a list?

Tags: leaflet

I'm trying to show the coordinates when you click on the map.

My code :

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s,h&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}', {
  subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']
}).addTo(map)

var marker = L.marker()

function onMapClick(e) {
    marker
      .setLatLng(e.latlng)
      .addTo(map)
      /*Here*/
      .bindPopup(e.latlng.toString()).openPopup() /*That shows LatLng(yourLat, yourLng)*/
}

map.on('click', onMapClick);
```

Can you help me to delete l.latlng() class before the coordinates ?

Answer (score 1):

Replace

`.bindPopup(e.latlng.toString()).openPopup()`

with:

`.bindPopup(e.latlng.lat+","+e.latlng.lng).openPopup()`

PS: Please work on your wording / naming of things. Your title and discription has nothing to do with your "question". I think you want to remove `LatLng` from the output of `latlng.toString()`